# jQuery - Removing text from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Markup looks like this....

```
<img id="holder" src="http://www.domain.com/images/title.size.jpg">
```

My jQuery looks like this....

```
var image = jQuery('img#holder').attr('src');
```

I get returned `http://www.domain.com/images/title.size.jpg` but really I just want `http://www.domain.com/images/title.jpg`. My question is.... What is the best way to remove everything from between the periods in the just the filename (and one period) so I am left with `http://www.domain.com/images/title.jpg`?

Recap: 
just need JS that checks to see if there's more than one period after the last slash, and if so, finds the position of the first period after the slash and the position of the last period and removes the chunk in the middle.

Comment: [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [other String methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype#Methods) -- this is a JavaScript question, not a jQuery question.

Comment: this is incorrect..`jQuery('#holder img').attr('src');`.. i wonder how you gettin the result..it should be `jQuery('#holder').attr('src');`

Comment: does your jQuery work ? you are looking for `#holder img`. It should be `img#holder`

Comment: This sytax is wrong `var image = jQuery('#holder img').attr('src');`

Comment: @KailashYadav Actually the syntax is not wrong, it just doesn't find the target element.

Comment: It should be just `#holder` or `img#holder`.

Comment: Sorry i just typed my example wrong. but getting the SRC of an image is not the problem here. I have that working.... I am trying to modify that URL. I will edit the example.

Comment: It shouldn't be `img#holder` because that's less efficient than just `#holder`. The results will be equivalent unless you have multiple items with the same ID (you shouldn't).

Answer (score 2):

I guess `size` is a number, not a string. If so, use this code:

```
var image = jQuery('img#holder').attr('src');
image = image.replace(/\.([0-9]+\.)/, '.');
```

With this code `www.example.com/image.640.jpg` becomes `www.example.com/image.jpg`.

If size is has a syntax like `640x480` use this (note the 'x'):

```
image = image.replace(/\.([0-9x]+\.)/, '.');
```

Comment: His question says _checks to see if there's more than one period after the last slash, and if so, finds the position of the first period after the slash and the position of the last period and removes the chunk in the middle._ so I don't think it's right to assume the format of `size` in between the periods is a number or something specific. You should just make the regular expression account for anything in between the periods.

Answer (score 1):

```
function removebetweendots(str)
{
    var arr = str.split("/");
    var filename = arr[arr.length-1];
    var n = filename.split(".").length; 
    var newfilename;
    if(n>2)
        newfilename = filename.split(".")[0] +"."+ filename.split(".")[n-1];
    else
        newfilename = filename;
    arr[arr.length-1] = newfilename;
    return arr.join("/");
}

removebetweendots("http://www.domain.com/images/title.size.jpg");
// returns .. "http://www.domain.com/images/title.jpg"

removebetweendots("http://www.domain.com/images/title.size.moredata.jpg");
// returns .. "http://www.domain.com/images/title.jpg"
```

Comment: Make sure your function is taking in a str parameter. For some reason I can't edit it.

Comment: @Broxzier I agree. A regular expression solution can be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use a regular, expression.

```
var getSize = new RegExp({},"");
```

{} needs to be whatever you want to match. I don't know if it is going to be .size. everytime or a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = jQuery('img#holder').attr('src'); //the image url
url_parts = url.split('/'); //parts of url broken by '/'    
extensions = url_parts.pop().split('.'); //extensions in url (last elements in url_parts broken by '.')

if(extensions.length > 2) //if more than two extensions
   url = url_parts.join('/')+'/'+extensions[0]+'.'+extensions.pop() //replace url by joined non extension parts of orignal url, /, first and last extension

alert("My filtered url: "+url)
```

Working http://jsfiddle.net/5jLbs/